# How to cache PostGIS views?

Tags: postgis, vector, cache

Does anyone knows if there exists a caching system for views or queries in postgis?
I have a system that gives information through a webpage using a postgis view as backend. The problem is that, sometimes the view is big enough that takes 5 seconds per user to serve the info. I know there's this system named geocache that works very good for raster data using wms protocol. I was wondering if there's a similar tool for vector / table data.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `TEMPORARY` (or better `UNLOGGED` if you use pg9+) table to store the precalculated data (along with trigger functions to keep it in sync), but that's not an out-of-the-box solution as you'd have to write the queries yourself.

But before you do that, you may want to try `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on your view query, you may be able to find bottlenecks to optimize it enough not to need a cache.